# C# LINQ - re-write nested ternary operator into helper function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My code is to order results based on value. It works, but has warning: extract this nested ternary operator into an independent statement

```
results = resultSets.OrderBy(e => e.Status == "Status1" ? 1 :
        e.Status == "Status2" ? 2 :
        e.Status == "Status3" ? 3 :
        e.Status == "Status4" ? 4 :
        e.Status == "Status5" ? 5 : 6)
        .ThenByDescending(e => e.Times);
```

How should I write this logic in helper function to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Is this an actual warning from the IDE? *extract this nested ternary operator into an independent statement*

Comment: Who's idea was it to have string statuses to start with. Save your self time effort and code and choose appropriate types so you dont have to switch to convert

Comment: @mjwills resultSets is IQueryable from EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create temporary table with status orders like this:

```
Status  | OrderNo
-----------------
Status1 | 1
Status2 | 2
Status3 | 3
Status4 | 4
```

In your query you can join on this table by status key and order by `OrderNo` column.

Benefits:

1. You can change order without changing code
2. You can add statuses dynamically

Comment: Thanks. Just a thought, since there's a limitation for me to create a table for this purpose, can I have a enum class for the statuses? For example, I have created: public enum MyStatuses { Status1, Status2, Status3, Status4, Status5}. How can I extend this idea further to achieve ordering?

Comment: @Henrix if your status in DB is stored in string, it won't help. It's better to store status as int value, and you will get natural OrderBy operation

Comment: Alright. Yes my DB stores in string. I'll see what I can do then...Probably have to accept this warning, if DB change is too intrusive...Good stuff, I will accept your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe make a helper to extract the number, such as:

```
private int GetStatus(string status, int defaultStatus = 0)
{
    int result;
    return int.TryParse(status.Replace("Status",string.Empty), out result)
       ? result
       : defaultStatus;
}
```

Then,

```
results = resultSets.OrderBy(e => GetStatus(e.Status))
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.Times);
```

Comment: This solution will work with `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable`. This can cause huge perfomance problems.